# Caliburn.Micro WPF: How can I create a new ViewModel that has a dependency?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have created one window called *ShellView* that will load or handle two user controls with the names *AView* and *BView*.

I have this setup already:

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(sender, e);
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.RegisterPerRequest(typeof(ShellViewModel), null, typeof(ShellViewModel));
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```

**AViewModel.cs**

```
public class AViewModel : Screen
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public AViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator.
    }
}
```

and this is the problem, how can I pass in an instance of the event aggregator inside the ShellViewModel?

**ShellView.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        // Should I create an instance and pass it in? If not, how?
        ActivateItem(new AViewModel(?));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro has a static class called `IoC` for this. You should do something like this:

```
ActivateItem(IoC.Get<AViewModel>());
```

Or you can do something like this, if it make sense:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        ActivateItem(new AViewModel(_eventAggregator));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first solution didn't work for me. Forntunately, you provided two solutions so I used the second one which works. A huge thanks!